# How to pass session value in foreach loop php

Tags: php, sql

it's a basic thing, but i am not able to get the required data. below is the code, while fetching count of absent from DB with logged in user id (empid=933) it's giving me the required record. but i want to fetch the same data with session ID of logged id user which is already created as $empid. but i am not able to pass this session value in below mentioned query. any one can help, i would appreciate ... thanking you in advance.

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="root";  
$password="";  
$db = "usman";  
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  

foreach($dbh->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ams where empid= 933 GROUP BY leavetype HAVING leavetype = "Absent"   
 ') as $Absent) 
{  
echo "<td>" . $Absent['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
echo "<br>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: So what is the data called in the session variable i.e. something like `$_SESSION['empid']` maybe. Give us a clue, make our lifes bearable

Comment: `'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ams where empid='.$empid.'  GROUP BY leavetype HAVING leavetype = "Absent"'`

Comment: php handles sessions data in a global variable named `$_SESSION`. It is an array. If you would like to see what is in this array, you can `print_r($_SESSION)` to watch any items contained in session. Then you can know which key is associated with your "empid" and store it in a variable, then pass it to your query.

Comment: this is seesion
    <?php 
        session_start();

           $empid = $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];
           $role = $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
            if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_username']) && $role!="admin"){
          header('Location: index.php?err=2');
       }
    ?>

Comment: manually its working when i assign the seession id then it is not working.

Comment: Try my code Muhammad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// first you must start the session to gain access to the session object
session_start();

$hostname="localhost";  
$username="root";  
$password="";  
$db = "usman";  

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);  

foreach($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
                    FROM ams 
                    where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']} 
                    GROUP BY leavetype 
                    HAVING leavetype = 'Absent'") as $Absent) 
{  
    echo "<td>" . $Absent['cnt'] . "</td>";    
    echo "<br>"; 
}
?>
```

Its also easier to give the `COUNT(*)` an alias `COUNT(*) as cnt` then you can use `$Absent['cnt']` as the columns name

Also I see no reason for the

```
GROUP BY leavetype 
HAVING leavetype = 'Absent
```

as you are using what I assume is a unique id to find the ams row

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  this error is given

Comment: Ahh didnt see your comment where you told us that the variable was in `$_SESSION['sess_user_id']`

Comment: Kindly Give me one favour how to add iff and else condition in it......i want iff count is availble ten show it else show 0.kindly

Comment: Kindly Give me one favour how to add if  else condition in it......i want if count is availble then show it else show 0.

Comment: You dont need an IF, this will do that anyway. If there are no rows it will return 0 in cnt

Comment: its retrun the empty row...not 0.

Comment: Then something else is wrong. A `select count(*)` query will always return a number either `0` or `> 0`. So your query must be failing

Comment: Looking at it. I dont see why a query with `where empid= {$_SESSION['sess_user_id']}` i.e. a unique id needs the rest of the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<?php
try{
  $db = new PDO("dbtype:host=yourhost;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8","username","password");
  $empid = $_SESSION['sess_user_id']; 
  $query=$db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as counts FROM ams where empid= ? GROUP BY leavetype HAVING leavetype = 'Absent'");
  $query->excute(array($empid));
  while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
   echo "<td>".$row->counts."</td>";
   echo "<br>"; 
    }
}catch(PDOException  $e ){
echo "Error: ".$e;
}
?>
```